# why my custom interceptor does not work

Tags: struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I define a custom interceptor used to log time, but it doesn't work.
here is my custom interceptor code:

```
public class TimeConsumedInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor
{

/*
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception
{
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String result = invocation.invoke();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time consumed: " + (end - start));
    return result;
}

}
```

I define a new xml file: ecs-default.xml(it is directly under `src` package)

```
<struts>
<include file="struts-default.xml"></include>
<!-- ecs-default package is abstract -->
<package name="ecs-default" extends="struts-default" abstract="true">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="ecsTimer" class="com.nader.interceptor.TimeConsumedInterceptor"></interceptor>

        <interceptor-stack name="ecsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="ecsTimer"></interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
           <!-- default stack used for ecs-default package -->
    <default-interceptor-ref name="ecsStack"></default-interceptor-ref>

    <global-results>
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

</package>
</struts>
```

and struts.xml file:

```
<struts>
<include file="ecs-default.xml"></include>
  <!-- define two empty package, / and /manager, extends ecs-default package -->
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="ecs-default">
</package>

<package name="manager" namespace="/manager" extends="ecs-default">
</package>

</struts>
```

I debug the code, in `com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation` class, `List<InterceptorMapping> interceptorList = new ArrayList<InterceptorMapping>(proxy.getConfig().getInterceptors());`, `proxy.getConfig().getInterceptors()` returns the 18 interceptors of defaultStack defined in struts-default.xml, my ecsTimer interceptor is not in it. so why? Is something wrong in my configuration?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultActionInvocation` is being created for every action execution. You just need to execute your action which is configured with your custom interceptor to see it in debug.

BTW there is already `timer` interceptor that does what you want.

Comment: I use struts annotation, I just do as you said,  `@ParentPackage(value = "json-default")
@Namespace(value = "/manager")
@InterceptorRef(value="ecsStack")
public class UserSearchAction extends ActionSupport`..., now it reports an error: Unable to find interceptor class referenced by ref-name ecsStack - [unknown location]. so how to solve it ?   this interceptor class exists for sure.

Comment: I solve it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600148/how-to-link-custom-interceptor-using-annotation. I think struts2 annotation is more complicated than xml configuration. Thanks very much.